# File Not Found when Bootstrapping AngularJS 1.6.2 with NodeJS and Express

Tags: angularjs, express, controller, bootstrapping

I'm trying to setup an AngularJS application but I keep running into issues when bootstrapping it, I am able to get it run on an express server via node.

But when I go to initiate a controller my developer tools console won't return the console logged hello world in the console.

I can't seem to figure it out as I have (as far as I'm concerned) written it correctly. I have used ng-app as well as as ng-view and tried to instantiate it with ng-controller calling the controller name.

**File Structue:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Contact List App</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-view>
    <h1>Contact List App</h1>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");
}]);
```

**Errors:**

[image]

EDIT: I have added the server.js code here:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public' ));

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running on 3000');
```

Comment: can you post your server.js here? maybe something wrong with the path of the server.

Comment: You should be using `/contactlistapp/controllers/controller.js`

Comment: See [Absolute File Paths VS. Relative File Paths VS. Root Relative Paths](http://www.webdevbydoing.com/absolute-relative-and-root-relative-file-paths/).